# Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app' while installing react native app in android emulator/device on macOS Catalina

Tags: android, macos, react-native, macos-catalina

I was trying to install a react native app in Android emulator/device on macOS Catalina using following command

```
npx react-native run-android
```

but unable to install it on emulator due to below error

> Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.

I already added,android sdk path in .zshrc file, those are as follows

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

but didn't get any success.I know i am missing something major here,
but how to install react native app in android emulator/device on MacOS Catalina.

Thanks in Advance.